# Are there functions for optimizing large STL files for 3D viewing?

Tags: matlab, 3d, compression

Problem Summary: I have large STL files of 3D modeled objects I would like to overlay and compare at specific sections from a CT scan which needs to be analyzed in Solidworks. I was wondering if there were functions or algorithms to 1.) compress the STL file 2.) Eliminate noise across the stl file through a normally distributed elimination(guassian elimination of discrete size callouts?) or lastly 3.) segment an stl file by specifying coordinate volumes to eliminate STL triangles outside of set volumes for smaller file size and specific area based examination of parts.

Attempted solutions: I've tried importing directly to Solidworks which fails - 13 million faces and 39 million vertices. I've tried compressing the resolution in solidworks - doesn't eliminate any triangles. I've tried using meshlab to convert the file to a DXF and import to Solidworks however this still failed and was too time consuming.

I believe there may be a solution using matlab to eliminate vertices and faces outside of the specified volumes as stated above or possibly do some sort of elimination algorithm to clean the "duplicated" similar faces.

Comment: The `STL` format is pretty simple, so you can probably implement #3 by just reading the input file and writing a new file, leaving out the triangles that contain a vertex outside the desired volume.

Comment: The only way to compress a mesh is to remove facets. Meshlab can do this with the Quadric Decimation algorithm. This will reduce the number of facets while maintaining the same shape (or as close to that shape as possible)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MeshLab for this purpose;
Open the STL mesh and use the Simplification: Quadric Edge Collapse filter that will reduce the number of triangles used to define the surface while preserving the original shape.

A simple video tutorial here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWM6EGVVNQU